# Referencing in Python when doing recursion while traversing a tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I'm currently learning about recursion in trees. I'm currently doing a function which finds the maximum sum of a path in a tree. In this case, a path is as a sequence of nodes from the root to leaf. So for example, given the following tree:

```
      5
     / \
    4   8
   /   / \
  11  13  4
 /  \      \
7    2      1
```

The paths would be:

```
[5, 4, 11, 7]
[5, 4, 11, 2]
[5, 8, 13]
[5, 8, 4, 1]
```

For this problem, the maximum sum would be 27.

I have this two versions of code:

Version 1: Using a list to update the maximum value

```
def maxPathSum(tree):
    maxSum = [0]
    
    findMaxPathSum(tree, 0, maxSum)
    
    return maxSum


def findMaxPathSum(root, currentSum, maxSum):
    if root is None:
        return
    
    currentSum += root.value
    
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        maxSum[0] = currentSum
        
    findMaxPathSum(root.left, currentSum, maxSum)
    findMaxPathSum(root.right, currentSum, maxSum)
```

Version 2: Using an int variable

```
def maxPathSum(tree):
    maxSum = 0
    
    findMaxPathSum(tree, 0, maxSum)
    
    return maxSum


def findMaxPathSum(root, currentSum, maxSum):
    if root is None:
        return
    
    currentSum += root.value
    
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        maxSum = currentSum
        
    findMaxPathSum(root.left, currentSum, maxSum)
    findMaxPathSum(root.right, currentSum, maxSum)
```

For some reason, when I update the value in the list it works. But when I do it in a variable it doesn't. In the version 2, I've tried printing `maxSum` after it's updated and is showing the correct value, but once I return it after the recursion is done, it stays as 0.

I'm almost sure that it has something to do with passing values as reference, but I don't understand how it works. Anyone mind explaining how this works?

Comment: You nailed it. You're mutating the list element versus reassigning a purely local variable. A better way to do the "by reference" thing would be to use a function closure. The `lst[0]` thing isn't very readable because it's not explicit about its intent.

Comment: You don't need to modify a reference. Have the recursive function return the new value of `currentSum`. The caller can then compare the value from the left and right recursions, and add the max to the current value.